# Bootstrap 3.0 & NiceScroll 3.5.0

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, nicescroll

I have a problem with `Bootstrap 3.0` and `NiceScroll 3.5.0`. These two plugins both require jQuery, however Bootstrap.js requires `jQuery 1.9.1` or higher and NiceScroll is not working with this version. Now I'm using `jQuery 2.1.3`. What should I do so I can use both Bootstrap and NiceScroll?

Comment: Does NiceScroll work with any version above `1.9.1`? Because I cannot imagine this is causing the issue for you.

Comment: Hope you don't have to support older versions of IE (since jQ 2.x kills <IE8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or you may consider the [$.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

just have to load the plugins in correct sequence.
In your case, v2.1.3 is your main version, so load it first. then load the v1.9.1, and then bootstrap,

after that call the jQuery.noConflict, you will have the $ pointed back to the v2.1.3

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery.noConflict( true );
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

On NiceScroll's GitHub page you can find version 3.6.0 that is quite more recent than the other and works with jQuery 1.8.3+ : https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll